# Changing/appending value in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, textarea

I am trying to pass-on values from a dropdown to the textarea.

The non-working code is:

```
<form name="f">
    <textarea id="change" name="change"></textarea>
    <br/>   
    <input id="docname" name="docname" type="text" list="docs" />
    <datalist id="docs">
        <option value="data1">
        <option value="data2">
        <option value="data3">
        <option value="data4">
        <option value="data5">
        <option value="dta6">
    </datalist>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms['f'].elements['docname'].onchange = function(){
        document.getElementById("change").value += this.value + ', ';   
        document.forms['f'].elements['docname'].value = '';
    };                 
</script>
```

However if I use `Input` instead of `Textarea` the code works as intended.

The working code:

```
<form name="f">
    <input id="change" name="change" value="">
    <input id="docname" name="docname" type="text" list="docs" />
    <datalist id="docs">
        <option value="data1">
        <option value="data2">
        <option value="data3">
        <option value="data4">
        <option value="data5">
        <option value="dta6">
    </datalist>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.forms['f'].elements['docname'].onchange = function(){
        document.getElementById("change").value += this.value + ', ';   
        document.forms['f'].elements['docname'].value = '';
    };                 
</script>
```

How can I use `Textarea` in place of `Input` and make the code work. I need to use `textarea` as I need multiple lines of text.

**PS: I am trying to create this http://jsfiddle.net/sumitcbrty/7zqn6j3u/2/ but just want textarea instead of using input field**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k7uwygaw/1/ ?

Comment: Thanks Arun, but I find that this too does not work. The value from the dropdown should 'stay' on the textarea. I am trying to create this - http://jsfiddle.net/sumitcbrty/7zqn6j3u/ but only replacing input with textarea.

Answer (score 1):

You should use innerHTML property rather than the value property. 
You should put logs in your code to debug it and view those messages in Developers Console.

**EDIT:**

Change in JS Code:

```
document.getElementById("txtArea").innerHTML += this.value + ', ';
```

Here is the working [plunkr](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqn6j3u/3/)

Comment: Thank a lot for the tip. I will surely keep that in mind. I am not a coder in any way and don't know much of it. I would really appreciate if you can tell me exactly how do I use the innerHTML. Would really appreciate your assistance :) I am trying to accomplish this http://jsfiddle.net/sumitcbrty/7zqn6j3u/2/ but using textarea instead of input field.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry for the late reply though.